# ECSlidingViewController Basic setup of pan gestures and menu reveal

Tags: ios, ecslidingviewcontroller

I am having trouble with setting up a basic ECSlidingViewController project.

I am using storyboards to set up my layout, but for the life of me I cannot get the unwind segue to work. When control dragging to the green exit button, it won’t allow me to make a connection.

Additionally, I cannot figure out how to add the pan gesture to the top view controller.

The transition fun example is the closest to what I am looking for (in regards to nag button to reveal menu and swiping the topViewController to reveal, as well as reset the top view controller when it is tapped) but I am having trouble picking apart the code.

Any insight on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

ChrisSamuelson is right about the unwind segue.

As for the pan gesture, you add it using `UIView`'s `addGestureRecognizer:`.

```
[self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture]
```

You may need to add it to another view in the hierarchy, it depends on how your `topViewController` is setup and where you want the panning to be enabled.

To support swiping and tapping to reset the top view, make sure you configure sliding view controller like this

```
self.slidingViewController.topViewAnchoredGesture = ECSlidingViewControllerAnchoredGestureTapping | ECSlidingViewControllerAnchoredGesturePanning;
```

Comment: self.slidingViewController is not showing up as a valid property. I was able to control drag to the exit properly now but nothing work. I prefer the programatic method used in the Transition Fun example, but I have the same problem of self.slidingViewController not being a property. I do not see in the example where this is set up. I have made sure that my view controller conforms to the ECSlidingViewControllerDelegate

Comment: Nevermind, forgot to add UIViewController+ECSlidingViewController.h! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Hi Michael, i'm using the TransitionFun example, but i can't get swiping and tapping to reset the top view. I noticed you pointed out some configuration that must be done, but i don't realize where to add that. Here's the repo of my project https://bitbucket.org/agustinhaller/slidingpanels/src. Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: I know that the configuration i need is in this (http://goo.gl/8aXCJ7) chunk of code of the original TransitionFun example. But i don't know how to configure that in my HomeViewController (http://goo.gl/IkwEyw). Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I manage to get things going. I changed my HomeViewController and now it's working. Here's what i've changed in case anyone needs it (https://gist.github.com/agustinhaller/9383946)

Comment: @Michael When i downloaded your code & try to run it, it is showing error "libPods-TransitionFun.a" not found, please let me know what should i do so it can work. I want to use fold navigation effect. Please suggest me what should i do ?

Answer (score 3):

In order for you to make a connection to the green exit button in a view controller higher in your view controller hierarchy you need to have a method with this signature:

```
- (IBAction)yourUnwindMethodName:(UIStoryboardSegue*)sender
```

where `yourUnwindMethodName` could be anything you choose. This method will appear when you attempt to make the connection to the green exit button.